# How to deserialize json to sealed trait using playframework in scala?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm new in scala and got stuck in object deserialization. I appreciate any help.

So the problem is, I have `sealed trait Permission` and some case objects that extend it:

```
sealed trait Permission
case object Administrator extends Permission
case object Dispatcher extends Permission
case object Editor extends Permission
case object NormalUser extends Permission
object Permission {

  def valueOf(value: String): Permission = value match {
    case "Administrator"  => Administrator
    case "Dispatcher"     => Dispatcher
    case "Editor"         => Editor
    case "NormalUser"     => NormalUser
    case _                => throw new IllegalArgumentException()
  }

  def stringValueOf(value: Permission): String = value match {
    case Administrator  => "Administrator"
    case Dispatcher     => "Dispatcher"
    case Editor         => "Editor"
    case NormalUser     => "NormalUser"
    case _              => throw new IllegalArgumentException()
  }

}
```

and I have `User` case class with `Permission`:

```
case class User(id: Option[Int],
                username: String,
                permission: Permission,
                firstName: Option[String]=None,
                lastName: Option[String]=None)
```

I've created `Json.reads[Permission]` and `Json.reads[User]`, but whenever I run the code, I get `No unapply function found` exception. I've tried to search for the same issue, but didn't get anything. Please help to solve this issue. Thx.

Using scala 2.11.x and PlayFramework

Comment: The `Reads` and `Writes` macros only work for case classes (eg. with `apply` and `unapply` methods to determine the structure). You'll have to write the serializers manually, but what should they serialize to?

Comment: The serialization is not important. I get JSON from Rest API and need to deserialize it. JSON is something like: `{"id":1,"username":"uname","permission":"Administrator",.....}`

Comment: It is important though. It seems like you just want to make it a `String`, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Play can automatically figure out the JSON reader only for case classes. In your case you have to define the reader for `Permission` manually:

```
implicit val permissionReads: Reads[Permission] = 
  __.read[String].map(Permission.valueOf)
```

This will throw an actual Exception in case of problems with permission format, instead of returning a `JsError`. To fix this you can use `collect`:

```
implicit val permissionReads: Reads[Permission] = 
  __.read[String].collect(ValidationError("unsupported permission format"))(
    Function.unlift(s => scala.util.Try(Permission.valueOf(s)).toOption))
```

If you don't want this long incantation `Function.unlift(s => scala.util.Try(Permission.valueOf(s)).toOption` you can reduce it by replacing `valueOf` (or adding a new function to `object Permission`) with a `PartialFunction[String, Permission]` or a function returning an `Option[Permission]` instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and attempts I came to this solution:
`implicit val permissionReads = (__).read[String].map{ permission => Permission.valueOf(permission)}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but it looks like you're using `case object`s which already have a `toString` method that gives back the name of the object, so the `stringValueOf` in the companion method might be reduntant.

Also, in case you no longer want to maintain that list of subclass objects, you might want to check out my lib here https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum, in particular the `enumeratum-play` project which comes with JSON serialisers and deserialisers built in.